# Line continuation with gfortran does not work

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm compiling my gfortran code using Mingw. I struggle to find a way how to continue my formula on the next line of the code. I tried to use continuation character `&` according to instructions for standard Fortran code but it doesn't work.

My code is following:

```
program test
    implicit none
    real :: a
    a=1.+ &
    2.
    print *,'Gfortran code  ',a 
end program test
```

and when I try to compile it the compiler returns the following statement:

```
test.f:4.13:
          a=1.+ &
                1
Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
test.f:5.8:
          2.
           1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

How do I continue lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it worked perfectly. Here the filename, content, execution command and gfortran specifics:

**test.f90:**

```
program test
    implicit none
    real :: a
    a=1.+ &
    2.
    print *,'Gfortran code  ',a 
end program test
```

compiled with: 
`gfortran test.f90`:

run with:
`./a.out`

output: 
`Gfortran code     3.00000000`

gfortran version `gfortran -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-    languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

**UPDATE:**

**The solution was to change the file suffix to .f90**.

The reaon,why this works is the following:
The **.f90** file is interpreted as FORTRAN 90/95/2003/... standard (backwards compatible).
If a file is called **.f**, it is interpreted according to the Fortran77 standard in [Standard Fixed Format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn6l/index.html). In this syntax standard you can see, that the first 5 charcters of each line need to be blank. The 6th is used for line continuation.

The following codeexample works in Fortran77 syntax: **test.f**

```
      program test
          implicit none
          real :: a
          a=1.+ 
     &    2.
          write(*,*)'Gfortran code  ',a 
      end program test
```

Attention to the & at position number 6! Your compiler seems to ignore the fact, that you didn't stick to Standard Fixed Format. If I try to compile your code with 77, I get a ton of errormessages, which refer exactly to that issue. This happens from time to time (some compilers are also case sensitive, others not).

**So, to avoid compile dependency, always stick to the language standards.**

By the way - here a nice [Fortran77 Tutorial](http://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/).

Comment: Now that we figured out, whats the solution, please see the Update of my answer

Comment: Two solutions... 1) use .f90 for free form  2) use -fixed as the compiler switch argument. (You can use -free for .for and .fixed for .f90 if one so desires to do so.

Comment: Hi, Markus, you're right, the problem was the suffix ".f90" and the fact that I did not respect fixed form standards. Thank you for your time and the detailed answer, I appreciate it. You saved me tons of time.